# Xcode 8.3.3 bracket highlighting is very inconsistent

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

When I use Xcode 1/10 times I will get bracket highlighting, but it is only for less than a second. Is there a setting I can enable to hold the highlight or make it more consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works if both the opening and closing bracket is visible on the screen and as far as I know, there is no settings to make it "permanent", it's intended to only be visible for a moment after you move over the opening/closing bracket.